# Border radius deforms cursor in input

Tags: html, css, input

I have input with border radius 1200px and it deforms cursor inside input. If i change border-radius to 10px cursor change to normal. This issue only on firefox, in chrome works perfectly.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  outline: none;

  border: 0.8px solid var(--color-gray4);
  border-radius: 1200px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: var(--color-gray1);

}

.input_title {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: var(--color-gray2);
}

.input:focus {
  border: 1px solid var(--color-primary);
  background: var(--color-primary-light);
}
```

```
    <form className={styles.container}>
      <label className={styles.input_title} htmlFor={inputId}>
        {children}
      </label>
      <input className={styles.input} {...props} id={inputId}></input>
    </form>
```

I tried to add padding to input, it worked, but not matched with design

Comment: What do you need to set such a massive border-radius for in the first place?

Comment: Could you  put a simple HTML/CSS snippet into your question which you have tested to prove it definitely shows the problem on Firefox as I can't see it (FF/Windows10) - the cursor looks fine to me. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example